# Is there an awk script for processing the trace file of wired transmission in ns2?

Tags: bash, awk, trace, ns2

I am trying to write an awk script for processing wired network transmission. So far I've gone through a lot of awk script but all of them are written for wireless technology and hence I find myself in a position of writing my own awk script for processing the trace file. I've some confusions regarding the metric calculation.

I've tried to write the awk script provided below but I've stumbled upon few questions. They are:

- If we send a tcp packet from node 0 to node 1 and suppose the packet reaches node 1 successfully but on the way back "ack" packet which is the acknowledgement packet gets dropped. Will we consider the packet delivery ratio to be 50% or 0?
- While determining the average delay, will we consider only the source-intermediate path or the whole source-destination path?
- While determining whether a packet has been successfully received, should we consider the final "ack" packet being received by the source as being received? Or just the destination receiving the packet as being received?

  ```
  {
    strEvent = $1;  rTime = $2;   from_node = $3; to_node = $4;
    pkt_type = $5;    pkt_size = $6;  flgStr = $7;    flow_id = $8;
    src_addr = $9;    dest_addr = $10;    seq_no = $11;   pkt_id = $12;

   if(pkt_type == "tcp"){

    if (pkt_id > idHighestPacket) idHighestPacket = pkt_id;
    if (pkt_id < idLowestPacket) idLowestPacket = pkt_id; 

    if(rTime>rEndTime) rEndTime=rTime;
    if(rTime<rStartTime) rStartTime=rTime;

    if ( strEvent == "+" && send_flag[pkt_id] == 0 ) {

      nSentPackets += 1 ; rSentTime[ pkt_id ] = rTime ;
      send_flag[pkt_id] = 1;
    }

    if ( strEvent == "r" && pkt_id >= idLowestPacket) {
       nReceivedPackets += 1 ;        nReceivedBytes += pkt_size;

       rReceivedTime[ pkt_id ] = rTime ;
       rDelay[pkt_id] = rReceivedTime[ pkt_id] - rSentTime[ pkt_id ];
       rTotalDelay += rDelay[pkt_id]; 
    }
    if(strEvent == "d"){
      if(rTime>rEndTime) rEndTime=rTime;
      if(rTime<rStartTime) rStartTime=rTime;
      nDropPackets += 1;
    }
   }  
  }

  END {
   rTime = rEndTime - rStartTime ;
   rThroughput = nReceivedBytes*8 / rTime;
   rPacketDeliveryRatio = nReceivedPackets / nSentPackets * 100 ;
   rPacketDropRatio = nDropPackets / nSentPackets * 100;

   if ( nReceivedPackets != 0 ) {
      rAverageDelay = rTotalDelay / nReceivedPackets ;
   }
   printf( "%15.2f\n%15.5f\n%15.2f\n%15.2f\n", rThroughput,rAverageDelay, nSentPackets, nReceivedPackets);
   printf( "%15.2f\n%10.2f\n%10.2f\n%10.5f\n", nDropPackets, rPacketDeliveryRatio, rPacketDropRatio,rTime);
   printf("Total Delay = %15.5f\n",rTotalDelay);
   printf("Ending Analysis\n");

  }
  ```

Comment: Welcome to SO please post sample of input and sample of expected output in your post and let us know then/

Comment: ~240 awk and perl ns2 scripts :  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rU_MFAEl1GCLMTJPLR3zbxPxkQQHkQ7T?usp=sharing